# Android device not recognized in Windows

Tags: android, flutter

I already enabled developer options and USB debugging, Google USB Driver is already installed.

When I plug my phone into my computer it enters debugging mode (I can tell that because the 'stay awake' option is enabled and the phone stays awake) but nothing prompts, I see no popup asking me to autorize the computer to access the device. I remember I tried some months ago and a popup would always show up asking this.

I already revoked USB debugging authorizations, my USB Configuration is set to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol).

But still, when I run `flutter devices` I get "No devices detected".

Also, when I run `adb devices` in the SDK/platform-tools path, the list of devices attached is empty.

I also tried restarting adb server, didn't worked.

Anything else must be done to make it work?

Comment: What is the model of your phone ? Are you sure that you have the drivers ?

Comment: @FlorentSebag my phone is an Asus Zenfone 4, I really am not sure if I have the drivers because I can't know which one is the correct one in their site. Sent them am email asking them to point me which is the one I should download. If you know it, please let me know. Thanks.